# Prefixing "Om" or "Jai" before mantra. What is the difference?

Tags: mantras

I want to know the significance of using `Om` and `Jai` before the mantra.

E.g. When I chant:

`Om Vishnu Devtaya Namah` and when I chant `Jai Shri Vishnu Devtaya Namah` am chanting 1 mantra more significant/powerful than other?

Comment: You can not prefix on ur own.. Mantras shd be chanted exactly as given in the scriptures.. so if those 2 mantras are found in the scriptures then both are equally potent .. usually all Mantras shd start with Pranavam (OM) with very few exceptions..

Comment: My guess it depends on the tradition. Prefixing mantras according to the Vedas should, as far as I know, exclusively be done with Om.

Answer (score 2):

Om is usually the starting point of most mantras. The reason is given below.

> **The syllable Om is the root from which the Vedas have sprung. (Every
>   rite, therefore, should commence with the utterance of that syllable
>   of vast import)**. Of him who has uttered for him the syllables Om,
>   Namas, Swaha, Svadha, and Vashat, and who has according to the extent
>   of his ability, performed sacrifices, and other rites, there is no
>   fear in respect of next life in all the three worlds.

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXVIII

A mantra starting with Jai (rare case) can also be chanted if given by a competent Guru.

Comment: My understanding is `Jai` is just `stuti` i.e. you are praising almighty. You can say`Jai Mata Pita`, `Jai Hind`, etc. but when you say `Om` you are calling powers/blessings. However I don't exact source to support my thinking, just in case it is right.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what Pradip Gangopadhyay stated in his answer that Aum is the starting point of all mantras as has been pointed out in the purport of the following verse [SB 6.5.26](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/5/26):

> At Nārāyaṇa-saras, the second group of sons performed penances in the
>   same way as the first. They bathed in the holy water, and by its touch
>   all the dirty material desires in their hearts were cleansed away.
>   **They murmured mantras beginning with oṁkāra** and underwent a severe
>   course of austerities.
>
> **Every Vedic mantra is called brahma because each mantra is preceded by
>   the brahmākṣara (aum or oṁkāra)**. For example, oṁ namo bhagavate
>   vāsudevāya. Lord Kṛṣṇa says in Bhagavad-gītā (7.8), praṇavaḥ
>   sarva-vedeṣu: “In all the Vedic mantras, I am represented by praṇava,
>   or oṁkāra.” Thus chanting of the Vedic mantras beginning with oṁkāra
>   is directly chanting of Kṛṣṇa’s name.

Though I don't think Jai is proceeded usually in mantras, it is more of a salutation for instance Jai Mata Di or Jai Shri Ram.